# How to use of "new" for polygons in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The definitions of `Circle` and `Polygon` are [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/) in *Graph.h* and *graph.cpp*.

For some exercise I need to have some unnamed `shapes` which are made using the `new` keyword. Both `Circle` and `polygon` are kinds of `Shape`.

For example if I have a `vector_ref<Circle> vc;` I can using this statement add an unnamed `Circle` into that vector: `vc.push_back(new Circle (Point (p), 50));` because I can supply parameters (which are a *point* and a *radius*) of a `circle` when defining it.

But for `polygons` the subject is different. 
For having a `polygon` I must declare it first, e.g., `Polygon poly;` then add points to it, this way, `poly.add(Point(p));`. Now it has caused a problem for me.

Consider I have a *vector* of `polygons`, `Vector_ref<Polygon> vp;` Now how to add (that is *push back*) a `polygon` using the `new` keyword just like I did for `circle` please? 
My code is this:

```
#include <GUI.h>
using namespace Graph_lib;

//---------------------------------

class Math_shapes : public Window {

public:
    Math_shapes(Point, int, int, const string&);

private:
    //Widgets
    Menu menu;
    Button quit_button;
    In_box x_coor;
    In_box y_coor;

    Vector_ref<Circle> vc;
    Vector_ref<Graph_lib::Rectangle> vr;
    Vector_ref<Graph_lib::Polygon> vt;
    Vector_ref<Graph_lib::Polygon> vh;

    //Action fucntions
    void circle_pressed()     { 
        int x = x_coor.get_int();
        int y = y_coor.get_int();
        vc.push_back(new Circle (Point(x,y), 50));
        attach(vc[vc.size()-1]);
        redraw();
    }
    void square_pressed()     { 
        int x = x_coor.get_int();
        int y = y_coor.get_int();
        vr.push_back(new Graph_lib::Rectangle (Point(x,y), Point(x+100,y+100)));
        attach(vr[vr.size()-1]);
        redraw();
    }
    void triangle_pressed()     { 
        int x = x_coor.get_int();
        int y = y_coor.get_int();
        vt.push_back(new Graph_lib::Polygon); // Problem is here!!
        attach(vt[vt.size()-1]);
        redraw();

    }
    void hexagon_pressed()     { 
        int x = x_coor.get_int();
        int y = y_coor.get_int();
        Graph_lib::Polygon h;
        h.add(Point(x,y)); h.add(Point(x+50,y+50)); h.add(Point(x+50,y+80));
        h.add(Point(x,y+100)); h.add(Point(x-50,y+80)); h.add(Point(x-50,y+50));
        vh.push_back(h);
        attach(vh[vh.size()-1]);
        redraw();
    }

    void quit()               { hide(); }

    // Call-back functions
    static void cb_circle   (Address, Address pw)  { reference_to<Math_shapes>(pw).circle_pressed(); }
    static void cb_square    (Address, Address pw)  { reference_to<Math_shapes>(pw).square_pressed(); }
    static void cb_triangle  (Address, Address pw)  { reference_to<Math_shapes>(pw).triangle_pressed(); }
    static void cb_hexagon   (Address, Address pw)  { reference_to<Math_shapes>(pw).hexagon_pressed(); }
    static void cb_quit     (Address, Address pw)  { reference_to<Math_shapes>(pw).quit(); } 
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Math_shapes::Math_shapes(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title):
    Window(xy, w, h, title),
    menu (Point(x_max()-150,70),120,30,Menu::vertical, "MathShapes"),
    quit_button (Point(x_max()-100, 20), 70,20, "Quit", cb_quit),
    x_coor(Point(x_max()-450,30),50,20,"x coordinate: "),
    y_coor(Point(x_max()-250,30),50,20,"y coordinate: ")
{

    attach(x_coor);
    attach(y_coor);
    attach(quit_button);
    menu.attach(new Button(Point(0,0),0,0,"Circle",cb_circle));
    menu.attach(new Button(Point(0,0),0,0,"Square",cb_square));
    menu.attach(new Button(Point(0,0),0,0,"Equilateral triangle",cb_triangle));
    menu.attach(new Button(Point(0,0),0,0,"Hexagon",cb_hexagon));
    attach(menu);
}

//-------------------------------------------

int main() 
    try {
        Math_shapes M_s(Point(100,100), 800, 600, "Math Shapes");
        return gui_main();
}

catch(...) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question directly?

Comment: Please show us code, instead of describing programming problems with dramatic prose.

Comment: What is `vector_ref`? It's not a standard class. Also, `vector_ref` or `Vector_ref`? Letter case is significant.

Comment: Also, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, together will the actual errors (complete and unmodified).

Comment: I added the code I had written.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to hold a pointer to your polygon until you've put it in the conatiner:

```
Circle* pPoly = new Polygon();
// ...
pPoly->add(Point(p1));
// ...
pPoly->add(Point(p2));
// ...
vc.push_back(pPoly);
```

you probably want to use smart pointers rather than raw ones as above but this is where you can start.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the exercise is of a chapter that the pointers are taught in next chapter!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
 void triangle_pressed()     { 
        int x = x_coor.get_int();
        int y = y_coor.get_int();
        Polygon *poly =  new Polygon(); 
        poly.add(Point(x));// add your points, I don't know if these are the right points
        poly.add(Point(y));// but have you tried this way? creating it, adding, then calling
        vt.push_back(poly); // push back without the move
        attach(vt[vt.size()-1]);
        redraw();
```

Comment: Thank you. It's very straightforward and fine. But do you have another way without using pointers please?

Comment: I'm unsure why you don't want to use pointers.  Without pointers you are limiting yourself to an extreme amount with c++.. when you do the new inline, it allows you to not have to create a pointer reference to the object.  But doing the polygon with pointers like above will be no different at all except you have a pointer variable with a reference to the polygon instead of it being created without a reference. If you do nothing else with this variable, it will act exactly like your other methods. It's a very minor difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to use the new operator, you would need to create a Polygon constructor that takes `vector<Point>` or `initializer_list<Point>` as an argument.

The other way around would be to create a helper function, e.g.
-- note that this is really suboptimal, there may be much better solution using move semantics, etc. (or even variadic template function for the matter)

```
Polygon* make_polygon(initializer_list<Point>& points)
{
    Polygon* poly = new Polygon();
    for (auto point : points)
        poly->Add(point);

    return poly;
}
```

And then just call `vp.push_back(make_polygon({p1, p2, ...});`

Obviously you could change the function to work without pointers simply by removing them alongside with the new operator call, but then it wouldn't work with your `vector_ref<Polygon>` type. You would need to use `vector<Polygon>` instead, as I assume that `vector_ref<T>` is just a typedef for `vector<T*>`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is also a way of solving the problem. But is there a way of solving the exercise without pointers except for new please?

Comment: As it seems, vector_ref has a push_back that takes reference, so it could work even without the pointers. The problem is the lifetime of the objects thus inserted. That, I think, is beyound the scope of this excercise.

Where did you get this excercise from? Could we have a look at it? If yes, it would be great if you could edit the question and add it there. Unless, of course, it's two pages of text on your textbook...

Comment: The reason I don't want to use of pointers is that I haven't beet taught about them. I'll learn about it in next chapter. The book I'm trying to read and solve its exercises is [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=programming%20principle%20and%20practice&pg=PA579#v=onepage&q&f=true) and the exercise is #4.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't specify what structures you should be using. If I were you, I'd swap `vector_ref` for `vector` then, as using `new` is not the usual* way of creating objects in C++ (unlike Java or C#). -- *depends on the consequences, I guess you'll read some about that further in your studies ;-)

Comment: Yeah you are right my friend, there may be many many ways for solving a programming exercise but at the time my thought went through using `Vector_ref`. :)